# Orbit Downloader botnet program removal [solved]

Tags: malware, virus, ddos, botnet, virus-removal

Recently (shortly after midnight on 10/8/2013) I installed and ran Orbit Downloader. After learning that the latest version  (4.1.1.8) has a botnet-like module included I immediately stopped the program and uninstalled.

In total, the program could only have been running for a few minutes (5 max) after installation. I have disconnected the computer from my home network, deleted all files it installed and came with, did a system restore to October 4th, and am currently running an avast boot time scan.

Are there any other steps I should take to assure that the program is is gone and can no longer cause any harm?

Is there any way to see now if my computer took part in a DDoS attack, or what the Bot-net could have done?

Source of info on the botnet-like module: http://www.welivesecurity.com/2013/08/21/orbital-decay-the-dark-side-of-a-popular-file-downloading-tool/

System specs: windows 7 (last update on the 4th), model is a Z570 (10249BU) (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834246156)

Update: avast has nothing to report

Comment: What's your internet connection? 5 minutes is hardly enough time to do any damage to anything and i personally wouldn't stress.

Comment: 20 mbps for downloading and 2.24mbps upload (timewarner). Good to know still is there anything else you would recommend?

Comment: Not really. I checked some of the links that the program is supposed to pull updates from and they seem dead. It sounds like only the KKM website is hard coded so yeah. Run AV and antimalware solutions and consult google if still concerned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System restore is almost enough . And since it has been discovered it has been flagged by almost every AV so yeah don't worry about it .